# Can Chocolate Frogs "die"?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, food

I know that they're simply chocolate figures that have been enchanted by magic, but **how long does that magic last**? Has anyone ever opened up an old box only to find a limp and possibly melted (aka dead) frog?

Comment: well - "they only have one good jump in them"

Comment: Imagining a melted one still jumping. Rank!

Comment: @NKCampbell What if takes years for them to get to use that jump?

Comment: ......magic? ;)

Comment: I hope they die when you eat them. That's pretty unsettling to the stomach otherwise

Comment: @Paul It's pretty unsettling either way.

Comment: Uh...do the books ever mention chocolate frogs as being enchanted at all? I think that might be an invention of the movie.

Comment: @DavidS I think it would be implied either way, but I suppose they could be caught in the wild. An interesting thought.

Comment: @SonOfSam No, I mean do the books ever imply they are animated in any way, and not just frog-shaped pieces of chocolate?

Comment: @DAvidS Oh. You mean were they only animated in the movies?

Comment: @SonOfSam As far as I can remember. If anyone can give a quote from the books that includes them moving then I'm wrong, but I'm fairly sure the books never refer to them as alive or anything like that. Just frog shaped pieces of chocolate. A lot of the Hogwarts train food is Halloween/magic-themed, but not magical. Maybe this issue is another question itself!

Answer (score 4):

## In the books, Chocolate Frogs don't seem to actually move.

Harry first encountered Chocolate Frogs on the Hogwarts Express, when the whole idea of the existence of magic was very new to him.

> “What are these?’ Harry asked Ron, holding up a pack of Chocolate Frogs. ‘They’re not really frogs, are they?’ He was starting to feel that nothing would surprise him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)*</sup></sub>

Ron has to explain what Chocolate Frogs are to Harry, and Harry reacts with wonder and amazement to the Famous Wizard Cards included with them. He doesn't say anything about the Chocolate Frogs moving, which, especially since magic was new to him then and he's surprised at the moving pictures on the cards, seems unlikely that he'd see a moving candy and not acknowledge it in any way.

> “No,’ said Ron. ‘But see what the card is, I’m missing Agrippa.’
>
> ‘What?’
>
> ‘Oh, of course, you wouldn’t know – Chocolate Frogs have cards inside them, you know, to collect – Famous Witches and Wizards. I’ve got about five hundred, but I haven’t got Agrippa or Ptolemy.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)*</sup></sub>

From Harry's lack of reaction, it seems very likely that Chocolate Frogs are simply frog-shaped chocolates, the same way Muggles have gummy worms, and the only really magical thing about them is the cards.

## In the movies, there isn't much on how long the spell lasts.

The only information about how long Chocolate Frogs last in the movie is when Ron tells Harry that it's unfortunate Harry's jumped away, since they only have one good jump.

[image]

Other than that, there isn't anything about if the enchantments placed on Chocolate Frogs can wear off or stop working.

Answer (score -1):

Based on films. If we can agree that the frog jumping out of the train in Harry's year one (1991) is the same one which entered it in Albus' first year (2017), we got at least **26 years**. I do not think it has ever been clearly stated, but it is that kind of "Feel nostalgic, old kid" film industry moment.

Comment: I think any years between movies would be considered out-of-universe